# How can I adjust memoir to work within org-mode?

Tags: memoir, geometry, emacs, book-design, org-mode

In lieu of typing bare-bones LaTeX code, and for other advantages
irrelevant to this question, I am using the `memoir` class from within
Emacs `org-mode`, with larger fonts for using the output initially on transparencies
and such.

```
#+title: Title
#+author: Author

#+LATEX_HEADER: \documentclass[letterpaper]{memoir}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[letterpaper, mag=1200, truedimen,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     width=4.0in, left=2.5in, top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tgtermes}

* Preface
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
...

* Preliminaries
** First section
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
...
** Second section
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat
at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec
...
* First Argument
** Section
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae
lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
...
** Section
Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a
faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel
...
```

When processed to PDF
(<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>)
the `.org` file above produces

[image: three pages from memoir through org-mode]

I already get several nice features with minimal effort:

- Although using `memoir` and hence defaulting (as I would like) to a book, I can set
  just the left margin to be much larger (for notes, etc) than the
  right margin, on both even and odd pages.
- What are normally "sections" (`*` prefix) do get top-level
  numbering (1, 2, ..).
- What are normally "subsections" (`**` prefix) get second-top-level
  numbering (1.1, 1.2, 2.1, ..).

But I am missing a few details:

- I would like the top-level numbering to be that of chapters, to be
  on a new page, and to have a `Chapter` prefix.
- There are currently no empty pages. I would like to force the
  chapters to continue leaving no empty pages, even if the preceding
  chapter ended on an odd-numbered page.

How can I adjust memoir to work within org-mode?

In the actual set-up the chapters will use `org-mode`'s `INCLUDE` directive

```
#+INCLUDE: "chapters/01-prelims.org
```

but it appears that even though this makes a difference in LaTeX, it is irrelevant when taking the org-mode route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the document class as a `#+LATEX_HEADER:`, you must do it with `#+LATEX_CLASS:`. If you inspect the exported `.tex` file from your example, you'll find:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
... the default export packages
\documentclass[letterpaper]{memoir}
... etc.
```

I'm actually surprised this compiles at all.

However, `ox-latex.el` does not know the `memoir` class, you can set this up with something like:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("memoir"
               "\\documentclass{memoir}"
               ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")))
```

Then you can build a consistently exported document with:

```
#+title: Title
#+author: Author

#+LATEX_CLASS: memoir
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [letterpaper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[letterpaper, mag=1200, truedimen,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     width=4.0in, left=2.5in, top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tgtermes}

* Preface
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
...

* Preliminaries
** First section
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
...
** Second section
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat
at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec
...
* First Argument
** Section
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae
lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
...
** Section
Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a
faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel
...
```

As to your specific requirements, I believe `memoir` fulfills them by default. But, if it you still miss something, now you can set it up to your liking, because the exported `.tex` makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. Curiously, it makes no difference whether I use `*` for chapters and `**` for sections (etc) or (as in your code) `**` for chapters and `***` for sections.

Comment: @Sam Ah, that's a leftover for when I was trying to include `\part` too. I'll correct it in the answer.